# How can I change the overlay behind UIAlertViewController on iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

Does anyone know how to affect that layer behind the UIAlertViewController that tints out the previous view in the background?

For instance, I need to flag it so Smart Invert will not affect it… but so far I can only get that for the Alert View Controller itself that draws on top of that overlay..

Comment: U can put a uiview in background before your alert controller pops up.
that ui view should be black coloured with 66% opacity for maintaining transparency.

Comment: @ShivamTripathi could you show an example? Objective-C if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.layer.frame.size.width,self.view.layer.frame.size.height)];
  newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.00 blue:0.00 alpha:0.66];
  [self.view addSubview:newView];
  [newView setHidden:YES];
  }

// presenting Alert Controller

[newView setHidden:NO];
  showAlert(@"Title", @"Message");        // Custom Defined Method